# mongoose model.save() not working

Tags: save, mongoose-schema

// I was just try to feed data into mongo table but .save() function not working neither it is giving any error
RUN: under terminal

> node feed.js

```
<!-- this is my product model product.js-->

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;
var productSchema = new Schema({
    image : { type: String,required: true },
    title : { type: String,required: true },
    description : { type: String,required: true },
    price : { type: Number,required: true }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

<!-- this my seeder file feed.js to feed data on mongo table  -->

var Product = require('../models/product');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/shopping");
var products = new Product({
     image : "post1jpg",
    title : "Lenevo Laptop",
    description : "long description here",
    price : '3500'
     });
 products.save(function(err){ <!-- this section not working -->
    if (err){ throw err; }
    });
```

Comment: Neither saving data nor returning any error